# Quando uma palavra nova passa ser considerada como parte da língua?

Tags: linguística, vocabulário, formalismo

Qual o processo que faz uma palavra nova parte da língua portuguesa? É algo oficial? Depende de legislação? Vale para todos os países? Tem como acompanhar isto?

Comment: Testando o *on-topic*. Mas definitivamente não é muito ampla. Só porque tem várias interrogações não significa que são várias perguntas. Já vi que vai haver um choque de cultura entre as diversas comunidades da rede.

Comment: Voting as off-topic as too broad... These types of questions, which are not particular to Portuguese, may better be asked over at Linguistics.SE.

Comment: OK, you changed the question...

Comment: Duvido que o processo seja igual para todas as línguas. Na verdade até onde eu sei, não é.

Comment: O processo é cultural, mas no longo prazo é mais ou menos igual para todas as culturas sim. Eu gosto da pergunta, e considerando que não tem um Linguistics.SE em português eu acho válida aqui.

Comment: Estou inclinado a considerar a pergunta off-topic. Ela realmente estaria melhor no Linguistics.SE.

Comment: @cpicanco depende, lá poderia ser escrito em português?

Comment: Realmente, não tem né. Quem sabe no futuro?

Comment: Não é por não haver um stackexchange onde fazer as perguntas que elas são *on-topic* aqui. Exemplo: perguntas em português sobre e.g. ciclismo, DYI, story-identification, física, matemática... são *off-topic*.

Comment: @ANeves Dizer que ela não cabe aqui argumentando que é porque não cabe aqui, não ajuda em nada. Perguntas sobre esses temas são assuntos completamente diferentes do que se pergunta aqui. O que o site ganha em proibir um assunto que faz parte do nosso tema? E o que ele perde em ter? Uma coisa é perguntar sobre algo que foge da audiência, outra coisa é perguntar algo que a audiência tem interesse. Os especialistas aqui são linguistas. Não são ciclistas, matemáticos, etc. Não vejo porque impedir perguntas sobre linguística em um site sobre isto.

Comment: Desculpa-me, @bigown , não me exprimi bem. Eu não acho que a pergunta seja off-topic (se achasse, tinha votado para fechar ou migrar). Só quis contestar o argumento que usaste: que poder-se ou não escrever em português no linguistics é relevante para decidir se uma pergunta é on-topic aqui. (Uma pergunta pode caber em vários sites, e também em nenhum.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os fonemas, a escrita e a língua materna da pessoa que produziu a palavra (ou sociedade na qual ela ocorre) me parecem critérios razoáveis para se determinar se a palavra faz parte de uma língua ou outra, se recebeu influência de uma língua ou outra, e assim por diante.

As palavras de uma língua não são propriedade de nenhuma instituição oficial. Aliás, elas não deveriam ser. Eu considero inaceitável, por exemplo, que uma empresa se ache no direito de cobrar pelo uso de uma palavra, simplesmente porque a tal empresa achou de usá-la para sua marca. Mas isso é outro assunto.

Palavras, como conjuntos de sons ou letras, são produto do comportamento das pessoas. Você é livre para criar palavras, ou deveria ser. Se ela entra ou não no dicionário, isso pode ser um mero detalhe. E quando os dicionários não existiam? E quando a própria metaliguagem (as definições de 'palavra') não existia? Ainda assim, poderia ser útil organizar o produto do comportamento daquelas pessoas no passado por meio do que é conhecido como "palavras".

Mas e se ela ocorre uma única vez? Se ela é proferida por um poeta uma única vez, pode passar a fazer parte da vida dos ouvintes pelo resto de suas vidas, mesmo sem o poeta saber. Mesmo no extremo, ocorrendo uma única vez mesmo, pode acabar fazendo parte da história de palavras seguintes. Por razões desconhecidas, tais palavras tendem ao efêmero e a uma morte prematura, o que certamente é uma barreira para a etimologia. Mas isso não as diminui, na minha opinião continuam sendo palavras com caracteristas de uma ou mais línguas. Parece claro para mim que a utilidade da definição "conjunto de sons ou letras" está para além das relações de poder institucionais que podem ser mais ou menos engessadas em uma língua.

Nem mesmo a própria língua, num lampejo que agora me ocorre, parece ter imutavelmente a posse das palavras. Se você considerar que as línguas estão vivas e constantemente mudando, isto é, as pessoas que falam a língua estão constantemente mudando o jeito que falam, escrevem, etc. Dessa maneira, surgem formas que são mistas, como em uma música famosa dos Mamomas Assassinas:

> O nosso work é playá.

Adiciono a isso, um fato curioso sobre a origem de nosso mais famoso dicionário: o Aurélio. Segundo [a descrição](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicion%C3%A1rio_Aur%C3%A9lio) na wikipédia:

> Apesar das críticas que se lhe são feitas, o Aurélio tornou-se o dicionário padrão na sociedade brasileira, estabelecendo a norma linguística e lexicológica - mesmo que esta não tenha sido a intenção do autor; a palavra "aurélio" chegou mesmo a se tornar um sinônimo para dicionário.

O fato é descrito em detalhes por e faz referência à pesquisa de Maria Biderman:

> Maria Teresa Camargo Biderman (2000). Aurélio: Sinônimo de dicionário? UNESP - Alfa, São Paulo, 44: 27-55.
>
> [fonte](http://seer.fclar.unesp.br/alfa/article/view/4198)

Comment: *me parecem (e não "parecessem")

Answer (score 2):

As palavras tornam-se parte da língua quando há uma grande parte de pessoas a utilizá-las e um dicionário decide incluí-las. Este processo pode demorar muito tempo, e, se o significado da palavra em questão for óbvio a partir dos morfemas que a constituem, será necessário que seja definida por um dicionário? :P

Comment: Entrou em qualquer dicionário, faz parte da língua? Se eu lançar um dicionário com palavras que  eu acho interessantes, faz parte da língua?

Comment: Sim. "Fazer parte da língua" só significa que é aceite por grande parte da população e por vários linguistas - não há nenhum processo formal.